# How to install Firefox from zip

Tags: software-installation, firefox

I recently downloaded the latest Firefox version on my Debian machine, having previously used Firefox ESR that came with the installation. How can I now link the extracted Firefox application to the Debian favorites section? I understand that I only have unpacked the zip file, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually "install" Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you downloaded, you didn't shared anything about the firefox archive that you've downlaoded, but there can be only two cases,

## 1. You downloaded the source code.

In this case, you'll need to make, compile, install, run the installer etc.

## 2. You downloaded the portable version.

If this be the case, you can run it directly as instructed here.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux

1. Download Firefox from the Firefox download page to your home directory.
2. Open a Terminal and go to your home directory: cd ~
3. Extract the contents of the downloaded file: tar xjf firefox-*.tar.bz2
4. Close Firefox if it's open.
5. To start Firefox, run the firefox script in the firefox folder: ~/firefox/firefox

Firefox should now start. You can then create an icon on your desktop to run this command.